# Latex letter: Address right aligned

Tags: latex, alignment, letter

I am using Latex letter class, and would like the address to be right justified.

The default is for it to be in a right aligned block, justified to the left. I am happy to change the letter.cls file, but haven't been able to figure out the right way to do it.

I have tried using sclttr2 instead but there are too many variables for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Left-aligned text in the right-aligned block

```
{
\leftskip = .7\hsize
\obeylines


Address:
12, International st., 
city

}
```

Right-aligned text in the right-aligned block

```
{
\leftskip = 0pt plus 1 fill
\rightskip = 0pt
\parindent 0pt
\obeylines


Address:
12, International st., 
city

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - but the address is still left aligned. Sorry I wasn't clear, or maybe I have put this code in the wrong place. 

I removed the \address field I had previously used, and put this 
after \begin{letter}{} and before \opening{Dear Sir/Madam,}

I ended up with the same thing as in the default letter class - an address that is in a right-aligned block but where the text is left-aligned within the block. I am looking for it to be right-aligned.